# Android Uploading App to Marketplace

Tags: android, key, google-play, apk

I have a project that I need to upload to the market. What is getting my really confused is the signing. I've seen lots of different tutorials all using different methods and the official Android dev site makes it worse. I've tried a few but they either don't seem to work or I don't really understand the process.

Are there any developers who can provide a easy to understand step by step link or tutorial that they have used (or created)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I know is the eclipse method. Right click on your project -> android tools -> export signed application package.

The rest is done by the assistent.

Comment: I tried this method, once the app was on the marketplace I downloaded it and got "failed to invalid signing" or something

Comment: This can be happening, when you have an unsigned version (you developing version) still installed on the device. Otherwise it shouldn't happening as long as you don't sign the app with the debug keys...

Comment: You sir are amazing :D also please check out my app need evaluation for my degree:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.finalyear.fitnessapp&feature=search_result